# Unauthorized response message while sending android build

Tags: codenameone

I have a basic subscription of codename one and don't use maven for my project.
I got an error while sending android build.

```
    Sending token build
Response message from server is: Unauthorized
Server provided no further details
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://cloud.codenameone.com/appsec/7.0/build/upload
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the subscription.

This is an authorization issue. It means your local token is expired. You need to logout in the Control Center app and log back in.